# List of completed missions?

Tags: pc, final-fantasy-13

Is there a list of missions the player has completed somewhere?

When I am looking on this [mission guide](http://www.gamesradar.com/final-fantasy-xiii-cieth-stone-missions-guide/) there seem to be screen shots from the gaming showing a list of missions.  How do I see that list?

I believe I have beat most of the missions, but I haven't gotten the achievement, so I suspect I have missed one.  I am hoping there is a list that tells me what I have completed somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're in Chapter 11 and you have the map open, there's a button you can press to see the mission list.  This button is indicated on the bottom right of the map screen.  It was the map button on the PS3, so try your map key <kbd>X</kbd>.

If not, here's where you can look:
[image: PS3 Mission List Button]

There are 64 missions in total.